# iOS - passing objects to a view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, viewcontroller

I want to pass some objects from a tableview to a view controller using parse.com . I tried this but it does not work: am I doing something wrong? any ideas? I added my detail controllers .m and .h files as well thank you..

```
-(void) tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
  NSLog(@"%i",row);

 PFObject *object = [self objectAtIndex:indexPath];


//Create a DetailViewController object
MyTableViewDetail * MTD = [[MyTableViewDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTableViewDetail" bundle:nil];


MTD.label1.text =[object objectForKey:@"columntext"];



//push the detail view controller object onto the stack

[self.navigationController pushViewController:MTD animated:YES];

 //tableView.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];


}
```

my detail.h:

```
@interface MyTableViewDetail : UIViewController{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imagedetail;

@end
```

my .m file:

```
#import "MyTableViewDetail.h"
#import "MyTableController.h"

@interface MyTableViewDetail ()

@end

@implementation MyTableViewDetail
@synthesize label1;
@synthesize imagedetail;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {


    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}




-(void)viewDidLoad{



[super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setLabel1:nil];
[self setImagedetail:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: What is the log output? Did your program crash?

Comment: the log is just the row number that was selected. runs on simulator without the desired output (does not change label1. crashes on actual phone.. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/F5EACDC2-35E4-451E-8478-4799xxxxxxxx/name.app> (loaded)' with name 'MyTableviewDetail''

Comment: Most likely you have created and delete some controls on the form before. The deleted controls was linked to some IBAction/IBOutlet before and therefore become invalid inside the nib. Try control+click on the owner icon of the controller in Interface builder to see if there is any invalid linkages.

Comment: fixed a typo. no error on actual device but still does not pass info. links are all there.. just added my other files for you to see.. (detail.h &.m) thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Per [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW19), it looks like all of the outlets in a NIB/XIB are supposed to be wired before `awakeFromNib` is called on any object in that NIB/XIB, but that outlets <s>probably</s> are not wired when `init`, etc., are called on the objects. You have to pass values to some strong properties and in awakeFromNib do all stuff.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.label1.text = self.columnText;
}
```

Comment: i dont get it.. i have read the documentation but why is that needed? i am new to xcode so can you please give me a more detail explanation..? btw it gets me error when i paste that on to the .m file

Comment: When you're calling initWithNibName, outlets are always nil, so if you want to set something to nil property there will be always nil. You have to set text for outlets after awakeFromNib is called, for example : MyTableViewDetail * MTD = [[MyTableViewDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTableViewDetail" bundle:nil];


MTD.someproperty =[object objectForKey:@"columntext"];
- (void)awakeFromNib:{ self.label1.text = self. someproperty;}

Comment: i get it now... still doesn't work.. would you be kind enough to take a look at it through teamviewer? thank you though..

Comment: i don't have teamviewer account, can you upload somewhere this sample project and i will se what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

solved. I created a separate property, e.g. "columntext" in MyTableViewDetail, and then

```
set MTD.columntext = [object objectForKey:@"columntext"];,
set self.label1.text = self.columntext; in viewDidLoad of MyTableViewDetail.
```